# Query for Highest Rated Video (Likes / Dislikes) SLOW when using ORDER

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-order-by

(Using MySQL) I have a table of videos (simplified):

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| videoID |  videoName  | videoAuthor |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | cool_video1 | rocky       |
|       2 | mixingTest2 | sensable    |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

and a table of video ratings, that is, every time a user likes or dislikes a video, a row gets added/updated in the videoRatings table:
for example, this would mean the video with videoID 1 has two likes and one dislike.  a "1" is a like in the videoRatings table.  a "2" is a dislike (simplified)

```
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
| videoRatingID | videoID | videoRatingTypeID |
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
|           121 |       1 |                 1 |
|           234 |       1 |                 1 |
|           290 |       1 |                 2 |
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
```

now, simple enough, all I want to do is grab the highest scoring videos of about 100,000 videos.
naturally, I do something like this:

```
SELECT Videos.videoID,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN videoRatingTypeID =1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS likes,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN videoRatingTypeID =2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS dislikes
      FROM Videos
      LEFT JOIN VideoRatings ON VideoRatings.videoID = Videos.videoID
      GROUP BY Videos.videoID
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

but this query runs in about a half of a second.  That worries me that when the videos table gets to >1mil, this will be even longer.  The videoRatings table is very small (~40 rows), and the videos table is ~100,000 rows.

I have indexes on the videoID obviously in the Videos table and indexes in my videoRatings table on videoID, videoRatingID, and a composite index on videoID+videoRatingID

I don't see a better way to do this.  I've read several posts about moving the order by outside.  But when I do that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Videos.videoID,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN videoRatingTypeID =1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS likes,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN videoRatingTypeID =2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS dislikes
      FROM Videos
      LEFT JOIN VideoRatings
      GROUP BY Videos.videoID
) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.likes DESC
```

there is zero improvement.

What is a better way to approach this layout, or this query? Thank you!

Comment: Which database are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited to say, MySQL

Comment: If you need a quick response, then I suggest that you have a summary table of likes and dislikes, which is maintained with a update/insert/delete triggers or directly through the stored procedure that now inserts likes and dislikes.

Comment: Because your `COUNT` is of computed values, and you're ordering by the count of those computed values, I think you're preventing the use of indexes, and forcing scans and sorts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I thought of doing that, to basically have a like or score column updated every time a like/dislike is triggered.  So that will be a near instant lookup (just order by score, no joins)... but, I was hoping there's something else I can do or something else I'm missing instead of adding that score column.  I'm skeptical if that is truly the best way.

Answer (score 1):

For real scalability, I think you will need a solution that maintains a summary table.  In the meantime, this might be faster:

```
select v.videoID,
       (select count(*)
        from VideoRatings vr
        where vr.videoID = v.videoID and
              videoRatingTypeId = 1
       ) as likes,
       (select count(*)
        from VideoRatings vr
        where vr.videoID = v.videoID
              videoRatingTypeId = 2
       ) as dislikes
from Videos v;
```

Be sure that you have an index on `VideoRatings(videoId, videoRatingTypeId)` (actually, the type id is not so important in the index, but it can help).

This replaces the `group by` on the whole set of videos and ratings, with index scans and small aggregations.  This will scale up, as long as the index for `videoRatings` fits into memory.

EDIT:

Your video ratings table is very spartan, containing little more information than the summary number of likes and dislikes.  Such a table might have the date/time of the rating and the person who did the rating, for instance.

BUT.  You are adding new ratings by `insert`ing rows into this table.  Well, it is almost the same operation to `update` another table (which could be `videos`) with the information.  Then think of your current table as the historical log.

The advantage to using `update`s is that you can truncate the log when it gets big.  Right now, you have to keep every rating since the beginning of time for every video.

Comment: when you say summary table would you recommend storing a score column within the Video row itself and updating it?  Or creating a table, for example, "VideoScores" and have VideoID column with a videoScore(likes, etc) column.  This may be beyond the scope of this question, but is this a general practice when storing this type of data? I imagine this type of "grab the highest score" has been implemented countless times and I am having a hard time to believe they did it this way, it seems too complex, perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: the query didnt offer any speedup (or slowdown), it ran around the same time.  I have the composite index you mentioned already as well. I should specify I will always need to keep the ratings table intact (i can never really truncate it) because users need to see which video they liked and disliked.  This is a common theme for likes/dislikes. For example, on stack overflow, if they deleted the log of you "up"ing some answer, then when you return to that page, the arrow would not be orange anymore.  Those logs must be kept forever

Comment: @AugieGardner . . . Try scaling the video ratings table to 100x or 1000x its current size.  Any timings are dominated by reading the videos table.

Comment: I can do that but the videos table will ultimately grow to > 1mil, I'm assuming that will botch performance?  I'm pretty much just wondering now if keeping the score in the Video row itself is the optimal way people do this.  In which case keeping a comment count would have to suffice as well, seems strange

Comment: @AugieGardner . . . If you have multiple counts, I'd be inclined to store them in a separate "statistics" table, with the same primary key as the `videos` table.  The logical separation makes sense.  Pre-summarizing commonly used data is a common performance-enhancement technique.